# Check 3 tables to see if an email exists in any of them

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check if an email address exists in any of the 3 tables of users I have.

I tried this:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM pims, dms, users WHERE pims.email = '{$email}' OR dms.email = '{$email}' OR users.email = '{$email}'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if (!result) {
            die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($result));
        }

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
            $duplicate_email_error = "That email already exists";
            $errors = array_merge($errors, $duplicate_email_error);
        }
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

---

It turns out PHP wasn't catching the error due to a the following:

The last 4 lines of the code above should read:

```
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
                $duplicate_email_error = array("That email already exists");
                $errors = array_merge($errors, $duplicate_email_error);
            }
```

With that, $errors was no longer empty and the code throws a warning to the user.

However, Gordon's suggestion is a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is doing a cartesian product of the three tables and then filtering out rows where one of the emails doesn't match -- very computationally intensive as well as inaccurate.

The following should do what you want:

```
  SELECT id FROM pims WHERE email = '{$email}' UNION ALL
  SELECT id FROM dms WHERE email = '{$email}' UNION ALL
  SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think the error was that $duplicate_email_error was not an array and I was using array_merge on it. But your feedback is very helpful. I changed my code.

Comment: I'm a little confused by why your code is actually working. I read that the UNION operator requires the tables to have the same columns, but my tables do not. Can you help clarify?

Comment: @Mike . . . The `union all` is on the subqueries, not the base tables.  All are returning one column called `id`, which presumably has the same type across all three.

Comment: Got it. It makes sense now. Thanks, Gordon!